# Android Studio app.gradle Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op

Tags: android, gradle

When performing a build of my project, I get this error:

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
```

Here is my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mls.client"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  // VOLLEY
  implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
  // GSON
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
  // GMS
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

What is wrong in my configuration? I think something with versions is wrong ....
I have also the error for the line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`: 
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 22.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0 less... (⌘F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

I would be happy if you could help me solve that issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that all of your libraries are up-to-date, because you're using a quite old play-service version, which should be 17.x.x or something. It could cause the clash because this lib has transitive dependencies as well. So I asume, that the play-services lib requires the support libs v 22.X.X, but you require 28.0.0, which will fail.

Thus, update all your dependencies and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the google() repo in the top level gradle file and also it should be before jcenter():

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
              google()
              jcenter()
          }


    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
       }
    }

    allprojects {
         repositories {
                  google()
                 jcenter()
      }
    }
```

remove this from your build.gradle file and sync again

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```